# Refunded non-consumable purchase still in the list Google Play Billing Library 2.1.0

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I use `queryPurchases()` to query as said in android dev.

**Process:**

Success purchase

Grant entitlement to the user

Acknowledge it

Refund using the the google dev console

I can still query the purchase, and user can use what they had refunded

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Thanks you.